# Azure Web App swap happening BEFORE warmup

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Since about a week when I publish a new version of our Web App and do a Swap from Staging to Production, it actually seems to swap *before* the warmup initialization is done.

As it is a large application it will takes more then five minutes to warmup the site, making the application unresponsive.

I have official Azure support, but it is taking a long time to respond to this request and I still have no answer that works.

I can't fix any issues on our platform or publish a new version without bringing the whole site down for eight minutes. This is a highly visited website, with paying clients.

Does anyone know:

- anything that I could investigate myself?
- a workaround or any tips that I can take a look at myself to try to fix or work around this issue?

[image]

**Extra information**

I do use `applicationInitialization`, and I see that Azure is hitting the pages - it just happens *after* the swap instead of *before*.

```
<system.webServer>
    <applicationInitialization>
        <add initializationPage="/nl" hostName="mydomain.com" />
        <add initializationPage="/warmup-application-for-azure" hostName="mydomain.com" /> (special page just for warming up services)
        <add initializationPage="/deeplink1" hostName="mydomain.com" />
        <add initializationPage="/deeplink2" hostName="mydomain.com" />
        [etc]
    </applicationInitialization>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I do have same issue and even I am using applicationInitialization still wont help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Comment: Btw same issue happens with Auto-scaling

Comment: Hi @VolodymyrBilyachat, thanks for your message and upvote. Did you also had it working before? I only have this problems recently - feels like a regression bug. I also have `applicationInitalization` in my web.config and I see Azure hitting the server - but *after* the swap is done.

Comment: unfortunately never works for us. this is what stopping use to deploy any time we are coordinating, when its out of most users hours.. We started our upgrade to .net core but still its work in progress.

Comment: But what hitting us hard is autoscaling since nodes are added and they are not warmed up....

Comment: Can you please reply to them https://twitter.com/vovikdrg/status/1099838521525690368

Comment: Hi @VolodymyrBilyachat, thanks I did reply.

Comment: What I am thinking Do you have slot specific properties? Because theoretically this can be an issue.

Comment: Hi @VolodymyrBilyachat, I do have that. I'm using i.e. LocalCache. According to the documentation this shouldn't be a problem for a warmup swap though. And it hasn't been a problem for more then a year.

Comment: Hey any news on this?>

Comment: Yes. I am using LocalCache and I got this response: "The default is 300 MB and you told me that your application is bigger, so this will definitely can help for your issue. Can you please make it the maximum 2000MB. [...] Insufficient memory for the local cache can lead often to issues like the one you are experiencing." - completely undocumented. I tried it out and for now it **seems** to work. I wait it out a bit and then post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, site down again while swapping. Apparently this was just a random factor? I have fully disabled local cache for now (and all other slot settings) but this is not a proper fix.

Comment: Hey, Did MS team come up with solution?

Comment: HI @VolodymyrBilyachat, not yet - they have "sent it to the development team" to take a look at it.. if you also have a 100% reproducerable case, maybe it also helps to send it to them.

Comment: Hey how is going with this issue?:)

Comment: Hi @VolodymyrBilyachat, it apparently was a bug on the machine it was running on. I tried asking for more explanation and background information (as we are building the future of our business on their platform) and asked them to reply to this thread to provide more details. It would be great to actually know at least if I can next time discover if it's a wrong setting on my side or a "bug on the machine" and how I can know the difference.

Comment: Microsoft: "There was an issue with the sequence of the actions which are need for the whole deploying and swapping process. This  is the only Information about the issue unfortunately, which I’m allowed to share with the customers. Please test the behavior with local cache enabled next week and let me know the results. "

Comment: Could be more transparent TBH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an Azure bug, confirmed by the Microsoft Azure team.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not 100% relative to this question but since I had similar issue with warm up I want to share how I solved it.

I used to have issue with auto-scaling because my nodes were not warmed up due to url rewrite module. So what if you have url rewrites in your app make sure that you are checking for

```
 <add input="{WARMUP_REQUEST}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
```

Now this is in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#custom-warm-up) and it has link [to common problems](https://ruslany.net/2017/11/most-common-deployment-slot-swap-failures-and-how-to-fix-them/)

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes hitting the site’s root URL is not enough to completely warm up the application. For example it maybe necessary to hit all important routes in an ASP.NET MVC app or to pre-populate the in-memory cache. That is where the Application Initialization Module can help.

When you use the warmup-functionality provided by IIS (and Azure) instead of those old-fashioned methods and if deploying to an App Service, just add a slot setting to **make sure it always triggers** such as below:
[image]

This tutorial explains how you can use the recently enabled `Application Initialization Module` to completely [warm up your application prior to swapping it into production](https://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/).

Comment: Hi Joey, thanks for your answer. Maybe it's not completely clear from my question, but I do have application initialization module working and it has been working for more then a year. 

It just suddenly broke since a week. I'm trying to figure out why or how I can workaround it (until Microsoft gets back to me with an answer/solution).

Answer (score -1):

So here is the important thing you should consider:

- Unless you specify which url address azure needs to request to your website, how can it knows. If you don't do that, it only calls the root of the application
- Even if you specify the url and your url needs to authorisation/authentication, how can azure sign in your website automatically and call the url that you specify.

You have got two option to deal with it.

1) Write your own warming up api to call your web application with authorisation/authentication. Then create a scheduler to call the application every hour or half an hour. It also allows you to keep the entire application up & running & warm. You can also set AlwaysOn feature under the Application Settings. You can also trigger this api on  your CI/CD pipeline after the staging slot deployed successfully.

2) If you don't want to touch your CI/CD pipeline or whatever reason and don't want to write api, you should sign in to your web application, go through each page and warm it up manually. Then you can swap without any problem.

Comment: Sorry but looks like you misunderstood an issue. Its not about auth its about calling url and make sure that cold start is done.